# Overloading operators outside of the class

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

So, i have a simple class:

```
class complex{

private:

    double a,b;

public:

    void setA(double a){ this->a=a; }

    void setB(double b){ this->b=b; }

    double getA(){ return a; }
    double getB(){ return b; }

    friend complex operator+(const complex&, const complex&);
};
```

And i have the actual overloaded operator here:

```
complex operator+(const complex& x, const complex& y){

    complex c;
    c.a=x.a+y.a;
    c.b=x.b+y.b;
    return c;
}
```

I must have the operator overloaded outside of the function. In order to have access to private variables (those also HAVE to be private) I befriended the class with the function. I don't know if that's correct way to do such things, but at least it works.
I want to be able to add an integer to both members. In main():

```
complex a;
a.setA(2);
a.setB(3);
a+5;
```

Would result in having a.a=7 and a.b=8. Such overload inside the class is quite easy to make (Again, don't know if that's good solution, if not please correct me):

```
complex operator+(int x){

    this->a+=x;
    this->b+=x;
}
```

But I have no idea how to make it outside of the class because i can't use "this" pointer.

Comment: Operators that are implemented inside of the class must omit the left-hand operand parameter and use `this` instead.  Operators that are implemented outside of the class must have the left-hand operand parameter and cannot use `this`. However, your class member `operator+()` is implemented wrong, you are not supposed to modify the values of `this`, the operator returns a new object so modify that instead.

Answer (score 3):

The usual approach to this sort of problem is to have member functions that define the reflexive version of arithmetic operators and free functions that define the non-reflexive version, implemented with the reflexive version. No friend declarations needed. For example:

```
class complex {
public:
    complex& operator+=(const complex& rhs) {
        x += rhs.x;
        y += rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    double x, y;
};

complex operator+(const complex& lhs, const complex& rhs) {
    complex result = lhs;
    result += rhs;
    return result;
}
```

Having `a+5` change the value of `a` is unusual, but if that's really wha you want, make `operator+(int)` a member. However, users would typically expect that `a+5` would leave `a` unchanged, and that `a += 5` would modify `a`.

Comment: @ard_evon - it's a spell-check-o. Fixed. Thanks.